# django error "Exception Type: NameError at /polls Exception Value: name 'urls' is not defined" for application link

Tags: python, django

I am django/python newbie and with the following apps "poll", I have created
as per the tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/

while accessing the

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls
```

The error detail can be found [here.](http://pastebin.com/WHzbCLsG)

```
#../djcode/mysites/mysites/urls.py file code
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
              url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
              url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here in file `/home/abuzzar/djcode/mysites/polls/urls.py`

```
urls(r'^$',view.index, name='index')
```

should be

```
url(r'^$',view.index, name='index')
```

Read more on [URL dispatcher here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher)